# Is this a nondeductive sudoku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I am working on the leetcode sudoku solver and my program can already solve most sudokus pretty quickly, yet there are some exceptions, for example:

```
['.','.','9','7','4','8','.','.','.']
['7','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
['.','2','.','1','.','9','.','.','.']
['.','.','7','.','.','.','2','4','.']
['.','6','4','.','1','.','5','9','.']
['.','9','8','.','.','.','3','.','.']
['.','.','.','8','.','3','.','2','.']
['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','6']
['.','.','.','2','7','5','9','.','.']
```

this one, the logic algorithm I implemented can go so far as

```
['.','.','9','7','4','8','.','.','2']
['7','.','.','6','.','2','.','.','9']
['.','2','.','1','.','9','.','.','.']
['.','.','7','9','8','6','2','4','1']
['2','6','4','3','1','7','5','9','8']
['1','9','8','5','2','4','3','6','7']
['9','.','.','8','6','3','.','2','.']
['.','.','2','4','9','1','.','.','6']
['.','.','.','2','7','5','9','.','.']
```

before it could not deduce any further (and I can't either). the algorithm I'm using is a simple one, the usual "if a row/column/subgrid has a particular number then block that number from being placed on that row/column/subgrid". the problem guarantees that there is one and only one solution to each input. I read somewhere that sudoku with only one solution *should* be able to be solved logically, yet this seems not to be the case. should I start implementing some "guessing", brute force algorithms or is there a bit of logic I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

.
Using standard rules, my solver [CSP-Rules](https://github.com/denis-berthier/CSP-Rules-V2.1) gives:

hidden-pairs-in-a-block: b1{n4 n8}{r2c2 r3c1} ==> r3c1≠6, r3c1≠5, r3c1≠3, r2c2≠5, r2c2≠3, r2c2≠1

swordfish-in-columns: n3{c3 c5 c9}{r9 r2 r3} ==> r9c8≠3, r9c2≠3, r9c1≠3, r3c8≠3, r2c8≠3

swordfish-in-columns: n5{c3 c5 c9}{r7 r2 r3} ==> r7c2≠5, r3c8≠5, r2c8≠5

naked-pairs-in-a-column: c8{r2 r9}{n1 n8} ==> r8c8≠8, r3c8≠8, r1c8≠1

naked-single ==> r3c8=7

hidden-pairs-in-a-block: b3{n3 n5}{r1c8 r3c9} ==> r3c9≠4

whip[1](https://github.com/denis-berthier/CSP-Rules-V2.1): c9n4{r9 .} ==> r7c7≠4

naked-pairs-in-a-row: r3{c5 c9}{n3 n5} ==> r3c3≠5, r3c3≠3

singles to the end

IMO, this makes this puzzle quite "deductive" - even elementary.

Comment: cool. doesn't answer my question though (should I make a guessing/backtracking algorithm?) , this is leetcode so I want something that could fit in <50 lines of code and consume less than 20MB of memory (for python at least, for faster languages the bar should be even lower)

Comment: Your question was "is this a non-deductive sudoku?". My answer is clear: no. You're now asking another question and nobody can answer it without knowing your goals. If you want to use only Singles as logical steps, obviously, you have to do some backtracking.